# C++ Plot a float variable, opposed to int, onto panel

Tags: c++-cli

I have the following code which plots variables to a panel graphically.

```
Point point1 = Point(20, height);
Point point2 = Point(20, 0);
buffGraphics->DrawLine(System::Drawing::Pens::Blue, point1, point2);
```

However, this is just a test and want to be able to plot float variables as I need to build a graph. How can you plot a float to a panel / represent one?

Comment: What exactly would not work, when you inserted float variables here? Also, it might be helpful to tell us which framework for drawing you are using

Comment: When i insert floats it then rounds them before plotting.

Comment: Which framework/library do you use for plotting? C++ itself does not offer `Point` or the class that you are using for `buffGraphics`

Comment: here are all my indcludes,   #include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

Comment: Presuming you use visual studio, please click on Point and press F12. Which file does visual studio navigate you to?

Comment: System::Drawing::Point

Comment: @shorty: That's not actually C++, but C++CLI. That's Microsoft's C++-like language, but it's different enough that we use another tag for it (changed that for you)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `PointF` instead of `Point`. `DrawLine` works with it as well and `PointF` accepts `float`s.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't really use C style casts like such: 
    `Point point1 = Point((int)x, (int)y)`      
They are unsafe and hard too spot/read. Instead use the following: 
    `Point point1 = Point(static_cast<int>(x), static_cast<int>(y));`

Alternatively you could modify the `Point` class too have methods returning the integral value. The benefit of this approach is that you could add extra functionality like the `ceil` and `floor` functions, while not having to create a temporary copy of a `Point`; It would look something like this:

`int   xtoi()       const { return static_cast<int>(x);        }` 
 
`int   ytoi()       const { return static_cast<int>(y);        }` 
 
`int   xtoi_ceil()  const { return static_cast<int>(ceil(x));  }` 
 
`int   xtoi_floor() const { return static_cast<int>(floor(x)); }` 
 
`...` 
`Point ptoi()       const { return Point(static_cast<int>(x), static_cast<int>(x)); }`

`...`